# Lost file mode information on ext3 directory hierarchy

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions, ext3

An entire directory hierarchy of mine lost its file mode info. E.g.,

```
ed@bob:~/dev$ ls -l nir.git/
ls: cannot access nir.git/test: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/log: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/config: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/app: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/Gemfile: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/tmp: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/db: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/doc: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/Rakefile: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/Gemfile.lock: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/lib: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/public: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/mkcoffee.sh: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/vendor: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/README: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/script: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/resttest.sh: Permission denied
ls: cannot access nir.git/config.ru: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? app
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? config
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? config.ru
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? db
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? doc
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Gemfile
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Gemfile.lock
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? lib
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? log
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? mkcoffee.sh
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? public
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Rakefile
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? README
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? resttest.sh
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? script
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? test
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? tmp
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? vendor
```

All directories under  `~/dev` were similarly affected. It was fixed by a `chmod -R 755 ~/dev/*` but I'm a bit nervous because I don't know what caused it.

The only thing that routinely accesses these directories is an rsync, which is kicked off by rsnapshot.

Any ideas?